# HTML - Changing a vector's padding without moving it

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to set an SVG object's padding (especially left and right) without changing the position of the image? 

With "padding: 0" the vector is centered:

```css
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 
 padding: 0;
 
 width: 100%;
}

svg {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <svg width="512pt" height="512pt" viewBox="0 0 512 512" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g id="#231f20ff">
    <path fill="#231f20" opacity="1.00" d=" M 233.53 36.81 C 272.28 32.86 312.05 39.30 347.45 55.59 C 405.05 81.71 450.23 133.75 467.57 194.62 C 481.09 240.80 478.82 291.41 461.18 336.18 C 448.25 369.26 427.13 399.06 400.30 422.31 C 370.62 448.21 333.86 465.92 295.06 472.82 C 238.24 483.30 177.49 470.11 130.26 436.78 C 103.34 418.03 80.65 393.21 64.43 364.68 C 46.45 333.21 36.53 297.21 35.77 260.98 C 34.70 217.81 46.74 174.41 70.02 138.04 C 89.46 107.45 116.54 81.77 148.11 63.98 C 174.30 49.16 203.60 39.90 233.53 36.81 M 244.22 52.17 C 192.83 54.90 143.03 78.39 107.86 115.86 C 83.83 141.03 66.68 172.52 58.00 206.18 C 47.74 246.93 50.24 290.96 65.89 330.02 C 81.45 370.25 110.30 405.19 146.74 428.24 C 162.88 438.69 180.65 446.39 198.98 452.06 C 229.29 460.92 261.67 462.52 292.73 456.85 C 348.47 446.71 399.28 412.22 429.01 363.97 C 452.34 327.12 463.25 282.59 459.47 239.11 C 454.88 180.74 423.44 125.17 375.89 91.05 C 338.30 63.32 290.87 49.27 244.22 52.17 Z" />
   </g>
  </svg>
 </body>
```

But as soon as I set the padding to a value different than 0, the position of it is changed:

```css
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 
 padding: 0;
 
 width: 100%;
}

svg {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%; 
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg width="512pt" height="512pt" viewBox="0 0 512 512" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g id="#231f20ff">
    <path fill="#231f20" opacity="1.00" d=" M 233.53 36.81 C 272.28 32.86 312.05 39.30 347.45 55.59 C 405.05 81.71 450.23 133.75 467.57 194.62 C 481.09 240.80 478.82 291.41 461.18 336.18 C 448.25 369.26 427.13 399.06 400.30 422.31 C 370.62 448.21 333.86 465.92 295.06 472.82 C 238.24 483.30 177.49 470.11 130.26 436.78 C 103.34 418.03 80.65 393.21 64.43 364.68 C 46.45 333.21 36.53 297.21 35.77 260.98 C 34.70 217.81 46.74 174.41 70.02 138.04 C 89.46 107.45 116.54 81.77 148.11 63.98 C 174.30 49.16 203.60 39.90 233.53 36.81 M 244.22 52.17 C 192.83 54.90 143.03 78.39 107.86 115.86 C 83.83 141.03 66.68 172.52 58.00 206.18 C 47.74 246.93 50.24 290.96 65.89 330.02 C 81.45 370.25 110.30 405.19 146.74 428.24 C 162.88 438.69 180.65 446.39 198.98 452.06 C 229.29 460.92 261.67 462.52 292.73 456.85 C 348.47 446.71 399.28 412.22 429.01 363.97 C 452.34 327.12 463.25 282.59 459.47 239.11 C 454.88 180.74 423.44 125.17 375.89 91.05 C 338.30 63.32 290.87 49.27 244.22 52.17 Z" />
   </g>
  </svg>
 </body>
```

I'm trying to make the inner content of the SVG object bigger to prevent overflow during animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left` to offset the change in position from the padding.

```css
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 
 padding: 0;
 
 width: 100%;
}

svg {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: -20%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%; 
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg width="512pt" height="512pt" viewBox="0 0 512 512" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g id="#231f20ff">
    <path fill="#231f20" opacity="1.00" d=" M 233.53 36.81 C 272.28 32.86 312.05 39.30 347.45 55.59 C 405.05 81.71 450.23 133.75 467.57 194.62 C 481.09 240.80 478.82 291.41 461.18 336.18 C 448.25 369.26 427.13 399.06 400.30 422.31 C 370.62 448.21 333.86 465.92 295.06 472.82 C 238.24 483.30 177.49 470.11 130.26 436.78 C 103.34 418.03 80.65 393.21 64.43 364.68 C 46.45 333.21 36.53 297.21 35.77 260.98 C 34.70 217.81 46.74 174.41 70.02 138.04 C 89.46 107.45 116.54 81.77 148.11 63.98 C 174.30 49.16 203.60 39.90 233.53 36.81 M 244.22 52.17 C 192.83 54.90 143.03 78.39 107.86 115.86 C 83.83 141.03 66.68 172.52 58.00 206.18 C 47.74 246.93 50.24 290.96 65.89 330.02 C 81.45 370.25 110.30 405.19 146.74 428.24 C 162.88 438.69 180.65 446.39 198.98 452.06 C 229.29 460.92 261.67 462.52 292.73 456.85 C 348.47 446.71 399.28 412.22 429.01 363.97 C 452.34 327.12 463.25 282.59 459.47 239.11 C 454.88 180.74 423.44 125.17 375.89 91.05 C 338.30 63.32 290.87 49.27 244.22 52.17 Z" />
   </g>
  </svg>
 </body>
```